# python telegram bot(Telepot) group chat

Tags: telegram-bot

I'm making telegram bot using telepot.

The group chat message work a handler when it started with '/'.

Is there a way to get all group chat message?

Comment: have you tried to modify group privacy of your bot via @botfather?

Answer (score 1):

there are 2 ways to get all the messages of a group:

1.your bot should be added as an admin in that group.

2. disable privacy mode in settings of your bot via @botfather(it is enabled as default(except for bots that are added as admin))

Answer (score 1):

Bots have a privacy setting that stops them from reading everything that is sent in a group. You can disable this privacy setting by talking to **@botfather**, or make your bot an admin of the group (admins see everything regardless of the privacy setting).

With the BotFather option just tell him `/setprivacy`, then choose your bot, and then choose `Disable`.

Admin settings are on the `top_pencil_drawing / administrators` if your are on the phone, 
and on the `three_dots_menu / Manage Group / administrators` if on desktop.